# Make Xcode 8 code signing with explicit provisioning profile

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile, xcode8

Is it possible to force Xcode to code sign with provisioning profile placed in custom location? I need it for distributed builds, because Xcode automatic provisioning management is totally awkward.

Currently Xcode displays the following error:

```
No profile matching '.../profile.mobileprovision' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching '.../profile.mobileprovision'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
```

if I enter custom provisioning profile in project settings:

```
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ".../profile.mobileprovision";
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ".../profile.mobileprovision";
```

P.S. `xcodebuild` works fine with custom provisioning profile.